# Step n before an operation in a C# for loop

Tags: c#, vb.net, loops

A standard "for" loop I use is something like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
```

which increments `i` by 1 every time after it passes thru a loop.
I was wondering if there is anything like a VB's `Step n` operation in C#'s "for" loop. I googled and found out the only thing I can possibly do is (assume `n=2`)

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i += 2)
```

That's fair enough. But that brings me to the next question. What if I want to change a loop that increments `i` BEFORE it goes into it, like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
```

Is there any elegant way to do it, or do I need to go into first loop already with `i` incremented and increment it at the end of each loop OR before beginning all loops after the first one OR do other crazy stuff?

```
i += 2
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{ i++; }
```

or

```
i += 2
for (int i = 0; i < x; i += 2)
```

or

```
for (int i = 0 - 2; i < x - 2; i += 2)
```

I assume incrementing before a loop might not be possible in all cases, hence i thought there should be some other way to do it.

Comment: if you want to use pre-increment you can do it twice like this `++(++i)`

Comment: Also, doing this: `for (int i = 0; i < x; i += 2)` is **NOT** "tho only thing you can possibly do" (to emulate a `step`). You can also change the value of `i` within the body of the `for` statement.

Comment: @Hogan That's not changing anything.

Comment: @RufusL If you enjoy inflicting cruel and unusual punishment, sure.  Manipulating the loop variable both in the body and in the loop statement is quite evil.

Comment: Downvoters, brave enough to explain the downvote or are you just lurking there where to cast your downvotes?

Comment: @Servy :) I just cringe when I hear, "the only possible way is ...". That's rarely the case.

Comment: Why not @Servy -- ++ should work on an rvalue.

Comment: @Hogan I didn't say it wouldn't work, I said it wouldn't change anything; it'd be just the same as using `i+=2`.  pre/post increment is semantically identical when that's the only expression in the statement and the value of the expression is ignored.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but it could very likely be due to the fact that the documentation for the `for` loop describes exactly how it works. Probably people frustrated with the lack of investigation? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx

Comment: @Hogan you cannot chain the `++` operator in C# like you can in C++.

Comment: @Hogan That is a compiler error in C#. It is legal in C++.

Comment: @Rufus L The documentation just confirms what I wrote above. I have no problem with incrementing by 1, my question was about incrementing by more than 1 before the loop starts. I believe it is not covered on msdn, nor anywhere else I could find.

Comment: @śmiglidigli From msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx: •The iterator section defines what happens after each iteration of the body of the loop. The iterator section contains zero or more of the following statement expressions, separated by commas: ◾assignment statement ...◾invocation of a method. So you can assign it to whatever `step` increment you want, or even assign it to the return value of some custom `step` method: `for (int i = 0; i < maxVal; i = GetNextStep(i)) { }`.

Comment: @RufusL yup, but that will still happen AFTER the first iteration, right? I was after an equivalent of "++i" for multiple steps.

Comment: Yes, the iterator happens after each iteration. For something to happen before the first iteration, you can either assign it directly, or call some function to do the initial assignment: `for (int i = GetFirstStep(someStateVariable); i < maxValue; i = GetNextStep(i)) { }`

Comment: Got it. Good I asked this question, even if it cost me reputation, coz I now see something was fundamentally wrong with my loops understanding.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I was wondering if there is anything like a VB's `Step n`

You have the right C# equivalent:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i += 2)
```

> What if I want to change a loop that increments `i` BEFORE it goes into it

I may be missing something, but it sounds like you just want to change your starting value:

```
for (int i = 1; i < x; i++)
```

Also note that:

- using `++i` or `i++` makes no real difference here, since you're not *doing* anything with the return value within the `for` statement, which is the only difference between using `++i` and `i++`
- you can't do the following:

  ```
  i += 2;
  for (int i = 0; i < x; i += 2)
  ```

  because you can't re-declare `i` as part of the `for` loop if it;'s already declared outside of the loop.

**EDIT**

The for loop `for (initializer; condition; iterator)` is functionally equivalent to:

```
{
    initializer;
    while(condition)
    {
        .. do something
        iterator;
    }
}
```

It sounds like you want some sort of `for` loop that is equivalent to:

```
{
    initializer;
    while(condition)
    {
        iterator;
        .. do something
    }
}
```

there is no such single-statement construct in C#.  If you want that series of events you'll have to use a `while` loop like the above or change the statements in your `for` loop to provide equivalent functionality.

Comment: You don`t think I am just calling a for loop just for a sheer pleasure of it, do you:)? This is a question solely about the for loop base structure, leaving alone what happens inside.

Comment: @śmiglidigli I think the point D Stanley is making is that, in the iterator of the for loop, it doesn't matter whether you do `++i` or `i++`, because that is the only line that executes in the iterator. They both end up with the same result.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean or what issue you have with my answer.  I made no mention of what happens inside the loop other than pointing out the fact that you can't re-declare an existing variable as the loop variable.

Comment: @D Stanley You wrote "using ++i or i++ makes no real difference here, since you're not doing anything with the return value, which is the only difference between using ++i and i++". I am not doing anything with this value (here on SO), since I was only after the base structure.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use `i` within the loop or not - `++i` and `i++` are completely equivalent unless you use the return value _immediately_ (e.g. `x = i++` and `x = ++i` will give you different values for x).  The value of `i` within the for loop will be exactly the same whether you use `++i` or `i++` in the `for` statement..

Comment: @DStanley So, let me try to understand. My understanding was ++i increments before I go into the loop, i++ increments after i leave the loop. No? If not, why do we have ++i and i++?

Comment: No - `++i` returns the value `i` was _before_ the increment, `i++` returns the value of `i` _after_ it's incremented. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w.aspx) for the operator gives a clear example.   It has nothing to do with the order in which things happen within the `for` loop.

Comment: @DStanley technically, the `for` loop is not **Equivalent** to your `while`, if you consider the scope of the variable `i` in the two cases.

Comment: @RufusL, DStanley I already accepted the answer as it seems right, but can you explain what you mean by the "scope of i"?

Comment: @śmiglidigli Sure, in the `for` loop example, the scope of the variable `i` is limited to the body of the loop. This means you can't reference it outside the loop. In the `while` example, the variable is declared before the loop, and it's value can be accessed after the loop finishes.

Comment: @RufusL ah, no, that's fine, I thought you meant the difference between both "while" loops which I couldn`t see:D thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

Just initialize `i` to `2` to start at `2` rather than trying to execute the looping statement before the body.